# Have proof A==>B how to proof not A ==> not B

Tags: isabelle

I have proof for let's say A ==>B but how to do not A ==> not B with basic proof in Isabelle.
I also want to know that i know A is the equivalent as B in propositional logic, and I have proof A ==> B but I can't proof the other way around. What is the general way to approach these two situations.

It really confused for me at the moment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not possible, because it's not true in general. You should be able to prove not B => not A though.

Comment: "A->B: If it's raining, the ground is wet", "notA -> notB: If it is not raining, the ground is not wet": which of these two is true? The short answer is that the contrapositive is the only one that is logically equivalent to the original statement. The inverse and converse are not (though they are logically equivalent to each other).